# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'desc' of null

Tags: javascript, java, postman

I developed function in javascript and java, but I have a problem when reading the data (Get), I have an error Unexpected.

also, when I tested in postman, it displays:

> Unexpected ''

this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'desc' of null at dataF
>   (view_rh.html:586)

when I did the debugging in Console, it shows to me **data** it's null

code JavaScript :

```
d3.json("getJson.jsp?dataType=rh", function(data) { 

     spinner.stop();     
     allRHJson=data;    
     select2_data_all = dataF(allRHJson,[],0)[1];       
     loadJson(null,allRHJson, select2_data_all ) ;       

     //d3.json(json, loadJson );
});

function dataF(node, leaves, index) {
  leaves.push({
    id: ++index,
    text: node.desc
  });
  if (node.children) {
    for (var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
      index = dataF(node.children[i], leaves, index)[0];
    }
  }
  return [index, leaves];
}
```

Also, in java, when i debugged ,  it shows to me :

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name
>   'ID'. at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError

this my part of my code Java:

```
connectionString = new Properties();
connectionString.load(input);
String dbURL = connectionString.getProperty("db.connection.string");
Class.forName(connectionString.getProperty("db.connection.driver"));
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, connectionString.getProperty("db.connection.user"),
        connectionString.getProperty("db.connection.password"));

Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
String queryString = "SELECT ID, ID_PERE, LIBELLE, DATA FROM " + connectionString.getProperty("db.view");
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(queryString);
HashMap<String, Level> h = new HashMap<String, Level>();
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

while (rs.next()) {

    String id = rs.getString(1);
    String idPere = rs.getString(2);
    String libelle = rs.getString(3);
    String data = rs.getString(4);

    if (h.get(id) == null)
        h.put(id, new Level(id));

    if (h.get(idPere) == null)
        h.put(idPere, new Level(idPere));

    Level n = h.get(id);
    Level p = h.get(idPere);

    if (p.getChildren() == null)
        p.setChildren(new ArrayList<Level>());

    n.setDesc(libelle);

    LinkedHashMap<String, String> dataMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

    if (data != null) {
        dataMap = (LinkedHashMap<String, String>) gson.fromJson("{" + data + "}", dataMap.getClass());
    }

    n.setData(dataMap);
    p.getChildren().add(n);
    n.setParent(idPere);
}
```

Comment: what does your view/table look like?

Comment: what you have configured in "db.view" property and also table/view definition will help to find the root cause for the same